# LoopTools install could not find mathlink executable

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, feyncalc

I tried to install packages: FeyArts, FormCalc, and LoopTools in Mathematica 10 under Mac OS 10.11.3 system. I installed them separately in the directory `/user/local` and recall them in Mathematica Notebook by

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]    
AppendTo[$Path,"/usr/local/FeynArts-3.9"]
    AppendTo[$Path,"/usr/local/FormCalc-9.2"]
AppendTo[$Path,"/usr/local/LoopTools-2.13"]
<<FeynArts
<<FormCalc
<<Install[LoopTools]
```

Both FeyArts and FormCalc worked very well, but LoopTools returned following massage:

```
LinkOpen::linke: \!\(\*RowBox[{"\"Could not find MathLink executable\""}]\). >>
```

Then I used automatic installation script [FeynInstall](http://www.feynarts.de/looptools/FeynInstall) and install these packages into other directories and recall them again, but nothing changed.

I also noticed, there are Ready-made MathLink executables for Mac OS X below [LoopTools](http://www.feynarts.de/looptools/) website, but not sure if these files could solve my problem.

Is there anyone who can give me some suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you simply contact Thomas Hahn directly? He is a very friendly person and also uses a Mac, so I guess that this would be the fastest and simplest way to resolve your problem.